# node.js app on ubuntu linux with postgresql on virtual box on windows client

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, virtualbox, node.js

I set up, ubuntu linux on virtual box. Then I installed postgresql and node.js 
So basically I made a clean installation and i want that  ubuntu handles my requests. 
When i run **node server.js** , a Sequelize.js error occurred.

**Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnetionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433**

PostgreSQL is listening on port 5432, and once i run node server.js,tables are created with no problem.

I think is a problem with my client, and I don't know why.

postgres.conf **listen_addresses='*'**.

pg_hba.conf  **host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust**.

I have little bit experience with Linux Ubuntu and configuration
So a big hug and thanks for who will help me